# upside down question/exclamation mark

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to use the urw-garamond font to write some text in spanish,
but the upside down question and exclamation marks aren't recognised properly..
I've saved the source document as utf8, so shouldn't it 'just work'?

my source is as follows:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

\end{document}
```

and the output is:

```
á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, £, a
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What has XeTeX to do with this?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but you have to compile with `pdflatex` rather than XeLaTeX.

Comment: Thank you, I was apparently confused. I thought that xelatex could use both ttf fonts and T1 fonts, and was trying to use xelatex with the garamondx fonts..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `pdflatex`, then you have to tell it what's the input encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\begin{document}

á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `xelatex`, then you have to use an OpenType font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond} % or another Garamond font you have

\begin{document}

á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this clears it up completely =) I'll be using EB Garamond then